# Could not find or load main class - Cannot find jar in folder

Tags: java, dependencies

Files:

```
/jars/deploy/lib/myStuff-abcdef.jar
/jars/deploy/lib/helloWorld.jar
/jars/deploy/lib/jobStarter.jar
...
```

Inside `/jars/deploy/lib/jobStarter.jar`, is `test.test.Main`.

test.test.Main.java

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("hello world!");
    //do other stuff
}
```

With the command `java -Dabcdef test.test.Main.class` I get the error

> Error: Could not find or load main class test.test.Main.class

How do I fix this?

Comment: from which folder are you running the command?

Comment: from `/jars/deploy`